# Perl. Интерполяция массивов в строках. Почему строка "2 * 4" преобразуется в 2 в числовом контексте?

Tags: perl

Здраствуйте!

Читаю книгу по языку программирования Perl, Изучаем Perl 5-е-издание...
Не понятно один момент, в книге написано следующее:

Один элемент массива при интерполяции заменяется своим текущим значением, как и следовало ожидать:

```
@fred = qw (hello dolly);
$y = 2;
$x = "This is $fred[1]'s place"; 
$x = "This is $fred[$y - 1]'s place";
```

Индексное выражение вычисляется по правилам обычных выражений, как если бы оно находилось вне строки. Предварительная интерполяция переменных не выполняется. Иначе говоря, если $y содержит строку "2 * 4", то интерполироваться будет элемент 1, а не элемент 7, по тому что "2 * 4" в числовом контексте (значение $y, используемое в числовом выражении) преобразуется в 2 ...

- Почему строка "2 * 4" преобразуется в 2 в числовом контексте ?
- Это же ведь одна строка, и почему вообще именно 2 ?
- Что имеется ввиду -> "Иначе говоря, если $y содержит строку "2 * 4", то интерполироваться будет элемент 1, а не 7" ... тут имеются ввиду сами значение или их индексы ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Почему строка "2 * 4" преобразуется в 2 в числовом контексте ?

Потому что такова судьба языков программирования с нестрогой типизацией.

> тут имеются ввиду сами значение или их индексы

Индексы, как результат интерпретации `"2 * 4"` => 2, `$y = 2-1`, получаем `$fred[1]`

А вообще, очень плохой пример. Я б так написал:

```
$x = sprintf 'This is %s\'s place', $fred[$y-1];
```

И вообще, [use PBP](https://perlmaven.com/perl-critic) (см. раздел "Policies")! ([на русском, очень приблизительно](https://kostya.livejournal.com/17615.html))

Answer (score 0):

По-поводу преобразования строки в число. Тут все просто, строка сканируется до тех пор, пока её можно интерпретировать как число, всё остальное отбрасывается.

То есть, если строка будет начинаться с символов, отличных от цифр, то она будет целиком отброшена. Если строка начнётся с цифр, то она будет интепретироваться как число до первого не числового символа.

Исключением тут выступает любой пробельный символ, например `\n`, он игнорируется в начале строки.

```
cat test.pl 
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use v5.26.0;

say "a1" + 1;
say "1 " + 1;
say " 24" - 22;

$ perl test.pl 
Argument "a1" isn't numeric in addition (+) at test.pl line 8.
1
2
2
```